# Convolutional filter design in neural networks by data clustering

Tags: deep-learning, cluster-analysis

My understanding is that filters in convolutional neural networks are going to extract features in raw data (or previous layers), so designing them by supervised learning through backpropagation makes complete sense. But I have seen some papers in which the filters are found by unsupervised clustering of input data samples. That looks strange to me how cluster centers can be regarded as good filters for feature extraction. Does anybody have a good explanation for that?

Answer (score 0):

Certain popular clustering algorithms such as k-means are **vector quantization** methods.

They *try* to find a good least-squares quantization of the data, such that every data point can be represented by a similar vector with least-squares difference.

So from a least-squares approximation point of view, the cluster centers are good approximations (we can't afford to find the *optimal* centers, but we have a good chance at finding reasonably good centers). Whether or not least squares is appropriate depends a lot on the data, for example all attributes should be of the same kind. For a typical image processing task, where each pixel is represented the same way, this will be a good starting point for later supervised optimization. But I believe *soft* factorizations will usually be better that do not assume every patch is of exactly one kind.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and reply. But my question is not about the representativeness of cluster centers. They can be representatives of data, or in other words, they can be the features we want. That would be fine if they are used as features, but they have been used as filter weights to extract the features. This is a completely different approach and I do not understand how multiplying data by its cluster centers could generate some other useful features.

Comment: They are chosen to be *representative*. So they are supposedly able to encode most of the information of the input. That is why they are more suitable as filters than random vectors.